# Adding user, IP Address to PostgreSQL logging

Tags: postgresql, logging

I assume I'm missing something easy in the docs, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to add the user id and IP address of the machine running the query in the log files in PostgreSQL.  I can see it clearly in `pg_stat_activity` once it's happening, but when doing post mortems on database issues, it would be very helpful to see these in the logs.

I doubt it matters, but my server startup is this:

```
$BIN/pg_ctl -D /apps/pgdata9.5.0 -l /apps/logs/postgresql start
```

I was hoping there was a setting in postgresql.conf, but if there it it's eluded me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html

add `%u %h` to the `log_line_prefix` in postgres.conf

there's a table with other options in docs above

update:

query `pg_settings.context` to check if you need to restart
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-settings.html

> Context required to set the parameter's value (see below)

eg:

```
t=# select context from pg_settings where name = 'log_line_prefix';
 context
---------
 sighup
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I've made the change and will bounce the server once there aren't any queries running.  It's the busy time of the day at the moment.

Comment: @Hambone: you don't need to restart the server. Just reload the configuration file, e.g. `select pg_reload_conf()`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name --  WOW!  I never knew that.  That's fantastic.  Thank you. Yes, this worked perfectly.